# Java JOGL file doesnt't compile - I have installed all the non-docs search results for "jogl" from USC

Tags: software-center, java, opengl

Title says it all. I have installed everything, yet javac behaves like nothing has happened - No OpenGL objects are found when I try to compile copy-pasted code from tutorials. None.

I'm using the command-line javac from OpenJDK and Eclipse with standard settings. No go with either.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to tell javac to add the jar files containing the JOGL classes on the classpath.

If you use JogAmp JOGL 2 then include the two jar files gluegen-rt.jar and jogl-all.jar on the classpath:

Example download the latest jars from JogAmp and compile a simple application from command line:

```
#install p7zip-full required to unpack 7z files.
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
#download and unpack the latest JogAmp JOGL release
wget http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/jogamp-all-platforms.7z
7z x jogamp-all-platforms.7z
cd jogamp-all-platforms
#download a simple JOGL example application
mkdir -p demos/es2
cd demos/es2
wget https://raw.github.com/xranby/jogl-demos/master/src/demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo.java
cd ../..
#compile the jogl example application using javac
javac -cp jar/jogl-all.jar:jar/gluegen-rt.jar demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo.java
#run the example jogl application
java -cp jar/jogl-all.jar:jar/gluegen-rt.jar:. demos.es2.RawGL2ES2demo
```

Example2 compile a simple jogl application using jars provided by the Debian/Ubuntu libjogl2-java package:
Ubuntu uses the names gluegen2-rt.jar and jogl2.jar

```
sudo apt-get install libjogl2-java
#download a simple JOGL example application
mkdir -p demos/es2
cd demos/es2
wget https://raw.github.com/xranby/jogl-demos/master/src/demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo.java
cd ../..
#compile the jogl example application using javac
javac -cp /usr/share/java/jogl2.jar:/usr/share/java/gluegen2-rt.jar demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo.java
#run the example jogl application
java -cp .:/usr/share/java/jogl2.jar:/usr/share/java/gluegen2-rt.jar demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo
```

Note that Oracle have stopped supporting JOGL 1 since 2009.
The JogAmp community maintains JOGL 2.
https://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/Overview-OpenGL-Evolution-And-JOGL.html
http://labb.zafena.se/?p=656 - The JogAmp community now maintains JOGL and Java3D

Most developers use JogAmp JOGL from inside Java IDE such as NetBeans and Eclipse, here is a link on how to setup your development environment.
https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE